# Python Pandas only drop one of two rows with NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean

I have the following dataframe:

```
d1 = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'event': ['c','c','e','e', 'e', 'f', 'f'], 'var1': [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 7, 7], 'date1': ['2020-10-18', '2020-10-18','2020-10-16', '2020-12-4', '2020-12-4', '2020-12-7', '2020-12-7'], 'var2': [pd.NA, 2, pd.NA, 3, 5, pd.NA, pd.NA]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

If you display it, it looks like this:

```
In[1]: df1
Out[1]: 
   id event  var1       date1  var2
0   1     c     2  2020-10-18  <NA>
1   1     c     2  2020-10-18     2
2   1     e     1  2020-10-16  <NA>
3   2     e     2   2020-12-4     3
4   2     e     2   2020-12-4     5
5   3     f     7   2020-12-7  <NA>
6   3     f     7   2020-12-7  <NA>
```

I want to achieve the following:

- I want to find rows which are duplicates for the subset ['id',
  'event', 'var1', 'date1'], for example row 0 and row 1
- If both have a non-nan value for var2, I don't want anything to happen
- If one of them has <NA> as their value for var2, I want this row to be dropped (for row 0 and row 1 this would mean dropping row 1)
- If both of them have <NA> as their value for var2, I want to keep one row and drop the other (so for example, drop row 6 and keep row 5)

Based on my example, my desired outcome would look like this:

```
   id event  var1       date1  var2
0   1     c     2  2020-10-18     2
2   1     e     1  2020-10-16  <NA>
3   2     e     2   2020-12-4     3
4   2     e     2   2020-12-4     5
5   3     f     7   2020-12-7  <NA>
```

I have tried a lot of different boolean indexing variants, but none of them seems to manage the case where I have <NA> for both var2 values (they always drop both rows instead of just one).
Can anyone help?

Comment: Use `df1[~df1.duplicated(['id', 'event', 'var1', 'date1']) | df1['var2'].notna()]`

Comment: @jezrael thanks for your answer! How could I run your code if I wanted to do the exact same for multiple columns, not only var2?